# Magento css from custom skin by addCss

Tags: css, magento

I want to load css file only for products in specific category. For that I'm adding

```
<reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss"><link>custom.css</link></action>
</reference>
```

on the custom design tab on specific category in admin panel. That gives me

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://domain.com/skin/frontend/base/default/custom.css" media="all" />
```

in the page source code.

The problem is, that this provide link from "base" skin, and I need to add it from "myCustom" skin.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://domain.com/skin/frontend/myCustom/default/custom.css" media="all" />
```

Any ideas how to do this using addCss or any other action that I can provide in admin panel/config file?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not set the value of "Skin (Images / CSS)" from admin. go to System->Configuration->GENERAL/Design->Themes->Skin (Images / CSS) and add your custom theme name.

Hope will help!

Comment: Unfortunately it is set.

Answer (score 0):

Your xml code is OK.

**File must exists in /skin/yourpackage/yourtheme/ to be loaded** (Not in /skin/yourpackage/yourtheme/**css**/ )